# Login Menu Not Showing in Guest Session in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.5

I am currently working on a Joomla Project where I assigned the Login user menu to the `Guest user group` and Logout user menu to the `Registered user group`. After making this change, the Login Menu is not showing when a user visits as a Guest. What could be the issue?

**Note: When the login menu is saved as public, it does show correctly.**

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: have checked the session?

Comment: also, check in com_users setting what is the default group for the guest user.